# Cordova returns Error: Cannot find module 'external-editor'

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

On Debian OS (10.0 / buster) I installed cordova with:

```
npm install -g cordova
+ cordova@9.0.0
```

When running cordova with or without any argument I get:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'external-editor'
```

The node, npm versions:

```
npm --version
6.10.1

node --version
v12.6.0

npm list
cordova@1.0.0 /opt/cordova
  |--- external-editor@3.1.0

Here it says: cordova@1.0.0 while the installation of cordova says: + cordova@9.0.0
```

I tried this:

```
npm install external-editor --save

npm WARN cordova@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ external-editor@3.1.0
updated 1 package and audited 6 packages in 0.536s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

However, the npm install did not help. This is the output when calling cordova:

root@/opt/cordova# cordova

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'external-editor'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/editor.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/inquirer/lib/inquirer.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/telemetry.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/cli.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:527:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/editor.js:7:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/editor.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/inquirer/lib/inquirer.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/telemetry.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/cli.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova'
  ]
}
```

Looking into the editor.js:

```
head /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/editor.js

'use strict';
/**
 * `editor` type prompt
 */

var chalk = require('chalk');
var editAsync = require('external-editor').editAsync;
var Base = require('./base');
var observe = require('../utils/events');
var { Subject } = require('rxjs');
```

I also tried re-installing cordova, but same result.

What is the reason for this ? - regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.  I installed the missing external-editor with:

```
npm install external-editor --save
```

But this does not install it in the scope of Cordova.

I had to install it globally using the -g option.

```
npm install -g external-editor
+ external-editor@3.1.0
added 6 packages from 11 contributors in 0.349s
```

Testing cordova

```
# cordova -v
9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
```

Solved.